# Convert String to Time Netezza

Tags: netezza

I am trying to create a new table that involves calculating a time difference. The table code works, but the time difference is storing as a string in the new table and I need it stored as a time data type. I tried using the cast function but kept receiving an error. Below is my code:

`CREATE TABLE DREW_HEAT_HEAT_SAMPLE_2 AS( 
SELECT HEAT_ID,
       (max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 1 then sample_type else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 2 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 3 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 4 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 5 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 6 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 7 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 8 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 9 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 10 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 11 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end)
       ) as concat_code,
(max(TIME_TABLE_ENTRY)-min(TIME_TABLE_ENTRY)) as TIME_DIFFERENCE
FROM JHINES.ORG_HEAT_HEAT_SAMPLE
GROUP BY HEAT_ID
)`

I need to somehow cast the TIME_DIFFERENCE field to the TIME data type. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

For the conversion to interval you must first make sure that you are subtracting timestamps.  Be careful when casting interval to time.  You will lose any values over 24 hours.

```
CREATE TABLE DREW_HEAT_HEAT_SAMPLE_2 AS(
SELECT HEAT_ID,
       (max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 1 then sample_type else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 2 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 3 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 4 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 5 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 6 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 7 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 8 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 9 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 10 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end) ||
        max(case when SAMPLE_COUNTER = 11 then '_' || sample_type  else '' end)
       ) as concat_code,
(cast(max(TIME_TABLE_ENTRY) as timestamp) -cast(min(TIME_TABLE_ENTRY) as timestamp)) as TIME_DIFFERENCE
FROM JHINES.ORG_HEAT_HEAT_SAMPLE
GROUP BY HEAT_ID
)
```